# how to find my angular version in my project?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have setup the angular code on my local machine. I need to know the version of the angular that I am using in the project. how can I easily find it in cmd prompt?

Answer (score 103):

There are several ways you can do that:

1. Go into `node_modules/@angular/core/package.json` and check `version` field.
2. If you need to use it in your code, you can import it from the `@angular/core`:

   `import { VERSION } from '@angular/core';`
3. Inspect the rendered DOM - Angular adds the version to the main component element:

   `<my-app ng-version="4.1.3">`

Comment: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ver) is an example on using method 2 above (programmatically)

Answer (score 61):

try this command :

```
ng --version
```

It prints out Angular, Angular CLI, Node, Typescript versions etc.

Comment: You can try the short version: `ng -v`

Comment: `ng --version`, `ng v` are working but `ng -v` is not working.

Comment: ng -v,ng v and ng --version are working fine in my system. My version is 7.1.0

Comment: The question was how to find the "project's" version. ng -v won't indicate the actual version being used by the project, only which cli versions are installed on the system. For instance, my ng -v command shows I have the angular cli version 9.1.2 installed, however in my case, the project was actually using angular core version 5.2.5. The better way to find the "project" version is to refer to Max Koretskyi's post above. Knowing the cli version is useful, but it's more likely you need to find the core angular lib version instead, especially when figuring library compat. and upgrade options.

Answer (score 39):

> For Angular 1 or 2 (but not for Angular 4+):

You can also open the **console** and go to the element tab on the developer tools of whatever browser you use.

***Or***

Type angular.version to access the Javascript object that holds angular version.

> For Angular 4+ There is are the number of ways as listed below :

Write below code in the command prompt/or in the terminal in the VS Code.

> 1. ng version or ng --version (See the attachment for the reference.)
> 2. ng v
> 3. ng -v

In the terminal you can find the angular version as shown in the attached image :
[image]

> 4. You can also open the **console** and go to the element tab on the developer tools of whatever browser you use. As displayed in the below image :

[image]

> 5.Find the package.json file, You will find all the installed packages and their version.

> 6. declare the variable named as 'VERSION', Import the dependencies.

```
import { VERSION } from '@angular/core';
```

// To display the version in the console.

```
console.log(VERSION.full);
```

Comment: 1, 2 and 3 shows:

`Angular CLI: 6.2.3
Node: 10.15.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 
... 
`

Comment: @alete You are using Angular 6 version.That's the resolution.

Comment: @alete Or let me know what command you are executing and what output you are getting in detail.

Comment: I'll mention this as it caught me out:  ng version looks in node_modules. So if you checkout a different branch, ng version still reports the previous branch version until you run a yarn or npm update.

Comment: @MortimerCat Thanks for the update, Will be useful for others !

Comment: @JohanMorales Thanks! please make sure to up vote the answer!

Comment: last option to check in html ng-version tag is best option

Answer (score 18):

define VERSION variable and import version into it.

```
import { VERSION } from '@angular/core';
```

Now you can use VERSION variable in your code to print version 
For example,

```
console.log(VERSION.full);
```

Comment: Thanks. This was so simple. This must be marked as answer

Comment: simplest answer.

Answer (score 16):

`ng --version` command will show only the **installed angular version** in your computer instead of the actual **project version**.

if you really want to know the **project version**, Go to your project, use the below command

```
npm list -local
```

[image]

Another way, check `package.json` to know the angular version

[image]

Answer (score 13):

For Angular 2+ you can run this in the console:

```js
document.querySelector('[ng-version]').getAttribute('ng-version')
```

For AngularJS 1.x:

```js
angular.version.full
```

Comment: This only works if you have compiled code available to you.

Answer (score 9):

You can also find dependencies version details in package.json file as following:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you try to check angular version in the browser, for me only this worked <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and paste below command in console:

```js
document.querySelector('[ng-version]').getAttribute('ng-version')
```

ex:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Browser > Inspect > Element >

   <.app-root _nghost-hey-c0="" **ng-version="8.2.11"**>
2. In terminal

   :> ng version 
   :> ng --version 
   :> ng -v

Comment: Method 1 is only available if the compiled code is available to you. Method 2 only gives the version of the angular CLI that you have globally installed, not the version of angular in which the project was written.

Answer (score 3):

app.component

```
import { Component, VERSION, } from '@angular/core';

name = 'Angular version' + VERSION.major;
```

app.component.html

```html
<h5>{{name}}</h5>
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to check which version of angular you're using is to launch your browser, right-click /inspect and look in the element tab. I found that to be most helpful.

Answer (score -1):

you can use **ng --version** for angular version 7