# What type of syntax i need follow weather angular V2 or angular V4?

Tags: angular

I am new to ionic and angular. I have installed cordova and ionic using command  npm install -g cordova ionic.
I have checked in package.json it's showing below

```
"@angular/common": "4.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "4.1.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.2",
"@angular/core": "4.1.2",
"@angular/forms": "4.1.2",
"@angular/http": "4.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.2",
"@ionic-native/core": "3.10.2",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.10.2",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.10.2",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
"ionic-angular": "3.3.0",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.1.1",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"zone.js": "0.8.11"
```

Kindly inform to me weather i will use angular 2 syntax or angular 4?
and also guide me how to install ionic with angular 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed from the package.json file and it says `"@angular/common": "4.1.2",` ... Then you just installed Angular version 4.1.2.

You can confirm which version you are using at runtime using one of the options discussed here: [how to find my angular version in my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502779/how-to-find-my-angular-version-in-my-project)

Regarding installing ionic ... there must be some documentation that provides that information.

Comment: I no need to install , i am using the command  >npm install -g cordova ionic, it's having Ionic CLI : 3.3.0 with angular 4.1.2. My question is shall i use for that application angular 2 syntax, it is compatible to angular 2 code.

Comment: Angular 2 and Angular 4 have the same syntax. They just added a few features (like an else on the *ngIf) and improved performance.