# Output Angular 2 Version in Browser

Tags: angular

Is there a way to get the version of Angular from the browser (aka in TS). With AngularJS, you can do angular.version.full to do this, but that does not work in Angular 2.

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44503125/2545680), let me know if there's anything else missing

Comment: Was about to answer, when I saw @Maximus comment, which is the right answer: `import { VERSION } from '@angular/core';` then `VERSION.full` will return you the version.

Comment: @Maximus is there an easy way to get other packages ie WebPack or jQuery that are in package.json in code, like getting {VERSION}?

Comment: it depends on whether they export the version or not

Comment: how would I be able to check? just do an import and see what is there?

Comment: check the documentation for the specific libraries you're interested in