# Selenium, Java and Angular: Element not interactable

Tags: java, angular, selenium

The site is running an older Angular version, 5.2.11.

I've got something that looks like a straight input field on the page, but maybe not so straight in the markup:

```
<div felt fieldname="approxCostDevelop" class="felt" e2e-selector="approx-cost-develop">
   <est-currecy-felt ng-model="develop.price" input-id="approxCostDevelop">
      <translate>Approximate cost of development</translate>
   </est-currency-felt>
</div>
```

When I try accessing this text field, selenium gives me and Element Not Interactable exception.

I've tried placing the e2e-selector attribute both where it is now, and after the input-id attribute field. I've also tried using the input-id attribut instead of the e2e-selector. Same result every time.

The way I create and access the WebElement:

```
//@FindBy(css = "[e2e-selector=approx-cost-develop]")
@FindBy(css = "[input-id=approxCostDevelop]")
private WebElement approxCostDevelopTextField;

public void setApproxCostDevelop(String approxCost) {
    pproxCostDevelopTextField.sendKeys(approxCost);
}
```

It's not a password field or any kind of special field. And it's visible all the time, from the loading of the page. The elements directly before it are a list of checkboxes, which all are interactable.

Comment: Have you tried adding a wait condition before sending keys? Something like `wait.unti(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(approxCostDevelopTextField))`?

Comment: To find out about the angular version:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502779/how-to-find-my-angular-version-in-my-project.

Comment: Mate Mrše: Yup. No change. The element is visible all the time, so it's not a visibility problem.

Comment: The angular version is 5.2.11. Pretty old.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the  element is embedded in the  tag.

I'm not very familiar with Angular, but: Instead of using @FindBy and creating a named WebElement, try just creating a WebElement with the same name as the input-id. Like this:

```
private WebElement approxCostDevelop;
```

Comment: @FrankH. That was stunning +1. Any explanation/documentation?