# How do I know which version of angular was used in a project?

Tags: angular

I have inherited an Angular project, but I don't which version of Angular was used to build it.

Comment: You can check in the browser developer tools under elements tab where you can see the DOM. Something like this:`<app-root _nghost-vuj-c0="" ng-version="8.1.0">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find my angular version in my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502779/how-to-find-my-angular-version-in-my-project)

Answer (score 1):

In your `package.json` file in the dependencies look for `@angular/core` line

Answer (score 0):

Go into node_modules/@angular/core/package.json and check version field.